# how to convert my laravel project to an api?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-passport

I have a `laravel` project, which is about Students and their courses.

This project has `CRUD` functions, where the user(mainly the school's admin) can create users and assign their courses. I have successfully created this project.

But now how do I make this an API?. I need to share the students courses to another website, therefore I need to create an API right?

I have never created an `API in laravel`, when I checked the documentation of Laravel, it has this topic called `API authentication using passport`, is this talking about requiring users to login first before accessing the API
?.

Would be very helpful if someone can explain a little bit about creating an API and where to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to give another website access to view the students courses. Is the data publicly available ? If yes, you don't need Authentication. But that means literally everybody with the API URL can access the data. Using Authentication on your API is entirely up to you.

Now, to create an API, it's very easy with Laravel. There are tons of free resources online like this one: https://tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-rest-api. Just google the topic for more.

Basically, the API works exactly like what you did in terms of controller and routing. In laravel 5.4, there is a separate route file for api located in `routes/api.php`. That's where you define your routes.

```
Route::get('courses', 'Api\CourseController@index');
```

This route will respond to `https://www.website.com/api/courses` and will link to the function `index()` located in `app/Http/Controllers/Api/CourseController.php`. You will have to create that controller yourself.

Looking at that route file, you can see something out of the box

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

It means the route `/api/user` will require authentication because of the `auth:api` middleware.

In your controllers so far, you return views. In api controller you will return response

```
public function index()
{
    $courses = Course::all();
    return response()->json($courses);
}
```

The application calling the website will receive a JSON object containing an array of courses. More about responses here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses

**About api_token**
The default API authentication offered by laravel works by checking `api_token` attribute from the users table. That api_token has to been present in the headers of the request sent to the api. Laravel will then use that api_token to identify the user making the request. In default application, to get a user, you do

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

Within your API controllers, you do

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
//Auth will look for api_token to get the user making the request
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!. I will go ahead and digest the information and try to create a simple project to understand this.

Comment: i came across this "api_token" in users table. can u explain me about this? is this an one time token created when the user is registered?

Comment: ic ic... so is it automatically created when a user is registered? thx @EddyTheDove

Comment: You create it yourself. a simple random string would do `str_random(60)` to get a random string of 60 chars.

Comment: sorry for the api_token , we need to create a random 60 length right , when adding the user

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt have to be 60. just a number below 255.

Comment: ic Thx@EddyTheDove. I have been studying the concept of api and OAuth 2 and got my self quite familiar. i started following this laravel 5.3 passport tutorial in the documentation. im at this point where it says "run gulp to recompile". what is gulp? and what is node.js? then another one vue.js and then Elexir .. this is all very confusing.

Comment: Gulp just helps you compile all your assets (js, css, images) during production. For instance if you want to minify your javascript files for production. vue.js is just a javascript framework like angular and reactjs. Elixir is an abstraction of Gulp, build by the Laravel team. I think you can get more info from Google with better explanation.

Comment: thxx EddyTheDove ,to create an api do i have to follow the vue.js method?. can i not create an api just by creating api routes and apicontroller?

Comment: Definitely. Vue.js is just for Vue developers. Litteraly, an api is simply a controller returning JSON. So you can build an api without ever building a frontend for that. Like you can build an api for a mobile app, so you will never touch any JS file on that api. Neigher vuejs, nor angularjs. Api routes + controllers returning data are enough for an API.

Comment: exactly, i dont know why nobody made any tutorial to simply explain how to create and api, every tutorial or link that i go in they are talking about a lot of other stuffs. if i can create an api just with the Api routes + controllers returning data. then what is the use of passport?

Comment: Passport allows you to identify WHO is making the request. Let's say it's a mobile app. You want to know which user is pulling what. That's when passport comes in. If you thinkpassport is too much for what you need, simply use `api_token`. Same result.

Comment: thxx EddyTheDove. So i have created a new project and set up basic auth scaffolding.  i have included a random string for api_token in the the user's table. now i try to access this api route : Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');.   this is redirecting me back to the home page and doesn't show the user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137047/discussion-between-eddythedove-and-mohamed-manas).